# aligning (float) issue cross browser

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser

I am having a problem with the aligning of an image (float left) and a div (float rigth).

It works fine on IE8, Firefox and Opera

It doesn't work fine in IE7, and Google Chrome.

I can't figure out what is going on.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I upload the page in [HERE](http://www.latabladegongora.com/defaultest.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is that you add the **float:left** property to your image in the appropriate row, in your code it would look like this:
`$('#imgShow').css({ 'float':'left', 'width': '450px', 'height': '300px', 'margin_bottom': '4px', 'padding-bottom': '8px' });`

I tested it in Google Chrome (8.0.552.208 beta, Ubuntu), and it seemed to work fine.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the right-floated div first in HTML.